# Is it possible to force SharePoint REST API exception to be in English?

Tags: sharepoint-api

I'm trying to identify and handle a specific error that I get as a response from SharePoint rest api, the problem is that the error text depends on the site language.
for example, here is the error in English site:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "Feature '[guid]' for list template '[number]' is not installed in this farm.  The operation could not be completed."
    }
}
```

}

and in French site I get:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "fr-FR",
        "value": "La fonctionnalité « [guid] » pour le modèle de liste « [number] » n'est pas installée sur cette batterie de serveurs. L'opération n'a pas pu être effectuée."
    }
}
```

}

Is it possible to get the English text regardless of the site language?